# Customize the Search Dialog

Tags: android, search, styles, themes, drawable

I'm trying to add consistent selectors to my application. Similar to the `drawable/list_selector`. I can do this for all list elements and buttons in my application. But when it comes to system tasks such as the menu and the search, I can't find a way to style these. I have read the hack to style the menu, so this question is geared more towards the search dialog.

**My Goal:**
I want to style the Search Dialog that appears when the search button is pressed. Specifically I would like to change the outline color of the text box and also change the color of the text box when it is in a pressed state.

Any ideas would help.

Haven't tried any code, my thought was to add styles the `searchable.xml` file but I feel it doesn't work like that.

Comment: why dont you use input Dialog ?

Comment: In essence write an entire custom search dialog? I guess it could be done, but I was wondering if there was a more straightforward way. I just need to change two colors!! (thanks for the response)

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?  If you did please post a solution.

Comment: I have not. If you only support ICS and above you could use the SearchBar and try to apply a custom style to that. I have not tried that myself as I need to support 2.3

Comment: You can do it easily. see the answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/44131089/3649347